# Facebook declined friend request wanted back

Tags: facebook

I accidentally hit the remove button on a friend’s request to Facebook and now he cannot add me again and I cannot even bring him up at all. What did I do? What can I do?

Answer (score 0):

It's possible when you reject friend requests on Facebook, that the profile could be detected as a potential spammer by Facebook's weird algorithms, which prompts you to block them. I would check your blocking settings. 
https://www.facebook.com/settings?tab=blocking